# Filter report filter in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

In the built-in, classic report UI, people can pick columns to filter on. We want to limit what entries show up in these columns, based on another column. Like...

```
Foo  | Bar
A    | 1
B    | 2
C    | 3
D    | 2
E    | 2
```

I want them to be able to filter on "Foo", but only if "Bar" is 2. So I only want B, D, and E to show up. I've tried ACLs on the table, business rules, UI policies, and while they can prevent records from showing up in the results, they don't seem to touch the options available in the report filter dropdown. So to be clear, the *results* are perfectly fine. Those are filtered. But I don't even want them to see the other options in the filter dropdown.

Is this even possible? On ServiceNow Jakarta at the moment, moving to Kingston soon.